# GCC4.8.3 generating invalid asm from intrinsics (operand size mismatch)

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, avx

I'm working on migrating a MSVC application to Red-Hat Linux and have run into some issues with an intrinsic that was used. I'm using GCC 4.8.3 with the following command line.

```
gcc -c file.c -o file.o -O2 -g -masm=intel -m32 -mavx -mavx2 -D_MMX_ -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-pre -fno-builtin-printf -Werror
```

The pseudo-code is something like this

```
#include <immintrin.h>    // AVX/AVX2

void func_with_intrins(int x, int y, int h)
{
  short ddx;
  short ddy;
  int yh;
  ddx = xpos & 7;
  ddy = ypos & 7;
  ...

  for (yh = 0; yh < (h>>2); yh++)
  {
    if ((ddx + ddy) != 0)
    {
      __m128i ddxw = _mm_set1_epi16(ddx);
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

I've read that the _mm_set1_epi16 intrinsic can be expanded to a vpbroadcastw and I've confirmed this by looking at the resulting assembly file.S

```
vpbroadcastw    xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [ebp-216]
```

With a definition from [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VPBROADCAST.html)

```
VPBROADCASTW xmm1, xmm2/m16
VPBROADCASTB/W/D/Q is supported in both 128-bit and 256-bit wide versions.
```

The error GCC gives me is

```
Error: operand size mismatch for `vpbroadcastw'
```

When I change the optimization level from `O2` to `O0` the assembly is much different and doesn't use the `vpbroadcastw` instruction.

Since I'm using intrinsics I'm at a loss as to what to do. Compiling the file as O0 is not an option. If I move the `__m128i ddxw` declaration to outside the loop that seems to compile but I think I would change the underlying functionality. When moved to before the for loop, the `vpbroadcastw` code takes two `xmm` registers (the stack variable is vmovdqa'd into an xmm register) so I figure gcc is running out of registers and therefore tries to invoke `vpbroadcastw` with the second operand being a stack offset.

Comment: Try removing the `-masm=intel` option.

Comment: That worked. But why? The new asm is `vpbroadcastw -216(%ebp), %xmm0`

Comment: Upgrading to gcc 5.x also fixes the issue for intel syntax.

Comment: It fixes the issue because apparently there's a bug in the code that puts the size modifier `xmmword ptr` on the memory operand.  That code isn't needed for AT&T syntax, so it doesn't manifest.  (It doesn't actually need it for Intel syntax either, since `vpbroadcastw` does imply the memory operand size, unlike for example `movzx`)  Using gcc 5 anyway is a good idea, because it generally makes nicer code at -O3.

Comment: I'm guessing that as part of the work for Skylake in GCC 5.x the fix somewhere came in?  _New ISA extensions support AVX-512{BW,DQ,VL,IFMA,VBMI} of Intel's CPU codenamed Skylake Server was added to GCC. That includes inline assembly support, new intrinsics, and basic autovectorization._